# Issue finding results in Microsoft Graph /me/drive/search endpoint

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm having a hard time figuring out how the `/me/drive/search` endpoint matches documents.

When I try `/v1.0/me/drive/search(q='myQuery')` I receive documents with the name `myQuery` back. This makes sense. What doesn't make sense is that if try `/v1.0/me/drive/search(q='.')` I receive a giant list of results from across my organization. It appears that these documents are accessible to me, but when I try to search for one of them by name they don't come up.

**Example**

- `/v1.0/me/drive/search(q='.')` returns many documents, one of which is named "My Test Document"
- `/v1.0/me/drive/search(q='My Test Document')` returns no results.

One would expect that the 2nd query returns the same document as the first query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've made a change that we believe should help for this specific query. Hopefully you'll get consistent results now!